# JavaScript attempt to create a new element not working

Tags: javascript

This feels like a beginner question with a pretty obvious answer, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.  What is the problem with my attempt below to create a new element and add it to the body?

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.setAttribute("id", "popup");
newDiv.setAttribute("width", "400px");
newDiv.setAttribute("height", "400px");
newDiv.setAttribute("backgroundColor", "red");
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(newDiv);
newDiv.style.position = "absolute";
newDiv.style.left = "25px";
newDiv.style.top = "25px";
```

Comment: Nothing.  I check it out in Firebug and everything seems to be quite alright, but it doesn't actually appear.  It's in an HTML document inside an iframe on the page.  Body has the div as a child, and the div's style attribute has everything set as I want it.

Comment: background-color, width, and height should be set with css

Comment: Also, in case you aren't, make sure the code is being run _after_ the `body` tag has been loaded and not just immediately in the `head`.

Comment: Just a simplification: You can use `document.body` instead of `document.getElem...TagName('body')[0]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Width and height **attributes** won't work with "px" in them and I am not sure about the background attribute either. Either way, the following does work and is the way you should do it:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.setAttribute("id", "popup");
newDiv.style.width="400px";
newDiv.style.height="400px";
newDiv.style.backgroundColor="red";
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(newDiv);
newDiv.style.position = "absolute";
newDiv.style.left = "25px";
newDiv.style.top = "25px";
```

Comment: I would recommend that the appending goes last. Either way, good explanation +1

Comment: Yeah, I thought about the appending as well, but didn't want to change the code beyond what was the bare minimum.

Comment: You have missed `newDiv.setAttribute("id", "popup");` witch would be much nicer just `newDiv.id="popup"`. The width and height could be needed as attributes and not in the style.

Comment: Hmm, I have heard so many arguments over that and aside of the fact that setAttribute("name") didn't work on IE I haven't ever heard a conclusive argument which one is better, so I didn't want to mess with that one. And width and height should **never** be attributes. Never never never, in the worst case you should set an style attribute with the width and height in it.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/4BBWj/2/
Either set newDiv.style.backgroundColor or set attribute style = backgreound-color:red

same for height and width.

and also put some content to see something.

Comment: Also need to do that for width and height.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best approach i think.

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.id = "popup";

newDiv.setAttribute("width", "400px");
newDiv.setAttribute("height", "400px");

newDiv.style.position = "absolute";
newDiv.style.top = "25px";
newDiv.style.left = "25px";
newDiv.style.backgroundColor = "red";

document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
```