# QUnit test of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I have a function, depend on

```js
Research.prototype._getLink = function(target, docLink) {
     if ($(target).hasClass("some class")) {
      return docLink;
     } else {
      return $(target).attr("href");
     }
    }
```

Here I call the function:

```js
var linkToGo = self._getLink(e.target, "docLink1");
```

I don't know how I have to write qunit test for it. 
I have written this and stuck:

```js
QUnit.test('Get link', function (assert) {
      // target which has class 'some class'
     var target1 = 
      // target which doesn't has class 'some class'
     var target2 = 
     assert.equel(self._getLink(target1, "docLink1"), "docLink1");
     assert.equel(self._getLink(target2, "docLink1"), "docLink2");
    })
```

Comment: `equel` is a typo for `equal`  http://api.qunitjs.com/assert/equal

Comment: Taplar, No I have certain class but I think it's now important in this case

Comment: Alright, so fix that typo, and see what issues you have remaining.

Comment: My problem is how should the variables target1 and target2 look like for the test to work

Comment: What do your methods expect?  That determines what they should look like.

Comment: My method, depending on whether e.target has a certain class, returns the corresponding link. In my test I have two targets, first target has certain class, second doesn't has. I don't know how the targets have to look like.

Comment: What do you mean?  You just said how they should look.  One should have the class.  The other should not.  The method in the else clause looks for the `href` on the element, so the element that is being provided can be any element that has `href` as a valid attribute.

Comment: My function works with event

Comment: You are not passing an event into that method.  You are passing a dom element into it

Comment: I cannot change the method

Comment: There isn't a change to be made.  Like I said, what you **are doing** is passing a dom element into the method.  All you have to do is do the same for your unit test.  Create a dom element, set the attributes on it, and pass it to your method.  You are testing the `_getLink` method directly, not through an event handler.

Comment: yes, but I don't know how create a dom element here

Comment: Then that is your real question, of which there are pre-existing answers on Stack Overflow that you should search for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript attempt to create a new element not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367207/javascript-attempt-to-create-a-new-element-not-working)

Comment: thank you a lot, Taplar.